# For any complex number $a$, find a pole of function $\cos(a(z+\frac{1}{z}))$ that is not $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> For any complex number $a$, find a pole of function $\cos\left(a(z+\frac{1}{z})\right)$ that is not $0$.

From my understanding, a pole is a number for which the function is equal to $0$.

But how would you find such a pole, if you don't know the exact number for $a$? I know that $\cos(z)={0}$ when ${z}=\frac{\pi}{2}+{n}$, so would i just use that fact to try to find a pole of the function?

Comment: A "zero of $f$" is any $z$ where $f(z) = 0$.  So you are not describing a pole.  A pole of $f$ is a zero of $1/f$.  Here, $1/f$ is $\sec(z)$.

Comment: So if i would want to find a pole, i would just have to take 1/f and then find where it equals to 0?

Comment: Yes. <!--  this space left blank -->

Comment: ok, thank you that helps a lot!

Comment: I'm having trouble actually finding when sec(z)=0, because i believe that it can actually never equal to 0? Or am I wrong?

Comment: One detail: you're trying to find where $\sec \left(a \left( z + \frac{1}{z} \right) \right) = 0$.  However, cosine is entire, so the only place cosine can have a pole is at $\infty$....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps is as next

$\cos(a(z+\frac{1}{z}))=\frac{e^{ia(z+\frac{1}{z})}+ e^{-ia(z+\frac{1}{z})} }{2}=0$
if and only if

$$e^{ia(z+\frac{1}{z})}=-e^{-ia(z+\frac{1}{z})}$$

if and only if

$$e^{2ia(z+\frac{1}{z})}=-1$$

if and only if
$\cos 2a(z+\frac{1}{z})+i\sin 2a(z+\frac{1}{z})=-1$ if and only if

$\cos 2a(z+\frac{1}{z})=-1$ and $\sin 2a(z+\frac{1}{z})=0$ if and only if

$2a(z+\frac{1}{z})=(2k+1)\pi$ equivalently $\frac{z^2+1}{z}=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2a}$ then you need to resolve the quadratic equation
$z^2-\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2a}z+1=0$ and as said on the comments, there are the zeros of the function, but the poles is for the function $\frac{1}{\cos a(z+\frac{1}{z})}$.

Perhaps, if you expand the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{\cos a(z+\frac{1}{z})}$, you need to observe how many terms with negative power has, on the poles and it is the order.